# How to simulate "MYSQL has gone away" error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running lots of cron job and once in a while there is a *MYSQL has gone away* error.

I've now written some code to handle the error, but how do I simulate the error on my localhost so that the code can be tested thoroughly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kill a long-running thread.

See: [`KILL` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)

The [documentation about that error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) also lists different causes, so you could emulate some of them (eg: [change the timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) to be very low, etc).

Answer (score 5):

If it was on another machine you could unplug the network cable!

Comment: I tried this (with forbidding traffic in firewall) but I think this is not the same, becuase MySQL cannot send the error message.

Comment: I think you'll find the error comes from the client library not the server.

Comment: I said to unplug not use the firewall

Answer (score 3):

Mock the (affected method in the) Database adapter and have it raise the error. That's the usual approach when unit-testing code that has dependencies on external resources. If you are not using PHPUnit yet, this is a great opportunity to get started with it.

Further reading

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object
- http://www.phpunit.de/
- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects